# I need to use the canvas API to determine if the student is under-13 (birthdate). How can I do that?

Tags: canvas-lms

I'm building an integration using Canvas REST API and need to identify which students are under-13, and which are over-13 years of age. In OneRoster there are demographic information including birthdate, but all I can find in Canvas (LTI) is gender.